# Sorting a group into sub groups based on two characteristics

Tags: algorithm

I think I have a moderately useful solution but really curious if anyone has a better way. I'm also unsure how to properly define the type of problem I have, which means I haven't done much Googling.

The problem:
I have an unknown number of players who are selecting roles for a game. Valid roles are 1-5. The players MUST select a primary role, but they also have an option for a secondary role. The options for their secondary role are "none", one of 1-5 (different from their primary), or "any". I must then put players into teams of 5, each team requires one of each number. The goal is to maximize the number of correctly formed teams.

My current solution:
Divide players into 3 groups: A) People who selected "none" as their secondary, B) People who selected a number as their secondary, C) people who selected "any" s their secondary

- Fill up teams with players from group A, placing them as their primary role.
- Count the number of open positions remaining in the existing, non-full teams
- Count the number roles represented by group B (both primary and secondary)
- Based on the count of open positions, start adding players from group B - the order for filling positions is biggest deficit to smallest deficit, with a preference to picking players who have as their other role a number with the biggest size (by representation) in group B
- Fill in the left overs with group C

If worse came to worse I could always just throw people into groups regardless of their preferred role, but ideally I would create correct groups.

Answer (score 1):

Do primary and secondary roles have the same bearing on team balance? If so, you could look at the problem from the point of the teams and the status of each team's current roles/needs.

For example, the first person on team A may be both 1 and 3, so team A has a 1 and a 3.  The next person on team A should not be a 1 or a 3 in either the primary or secondary role.  Using the remaining team needs (roles 2,4,5) you can iterate through the possible members until either 1) the team is filled/balanced or 2) there are no remaining candidates.

Is there more to the problem? I get the feeling I'm not getting the whole issue.

Comment: Unlike I'm misreading @user1857842's question, this sounds like a world-of-warcraft type of situation, where once you're *in* a group, you're doing one role (tank/heal/dps).  However, you can list yourself as capable of doing multiple jobs, so the group-finder can group you with other people to make a viable group.  So the first person on team A can be doing job 1 or job 3, but not both.  An ideal solution would put as many people into groups as possible, without leaving un-grouped players that can only do an over-supplied role.

Comment: @PeterCordes Correct, though the game is actually League of Legends!

Comment: @Raspberry For my purposes, I assume the primary/secondary choice does not affect team balance. However, if tied I would default to a user's primary.